# Exception trying to create an ObservableCollection in an extension method

Tags: linq-to-entities, extension-methods, observablecollection

We use ObservableCollections quite a bit in our view models as we are using MVVM, and to save some typing, I decided it would be useful to have an extension method that converted an IEnumerable directly to an ObservableCollection, instead of having to create a new ObservableCollection each time.

Thus, instead of typing...

```
ObservableCollection fred = new ObservableCollection(myCollection);
```

...we could type...

```
ObservableCollection fred = myCollection.ToObservableCollection();
```

Obviously, in the contrived example above there is little benefit to this, but in a bigger Linq query, this could clean the code up quite a bit.

Anyway, I wrote a simple extension method like this...

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) {
  if (collection != null) {
    return new ObservableCollection<T>(collection);
  }
  throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
}
```

However, when I try to use this, I get an exception...

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[VisionRT.CRM.Entities.SiteOverview] ToObservableCollection[SiteOverview](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VisionRT.CRM.Entities.SiteOverview])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I would understand this if it weren't for the fact that the ToList() extension method does exactly the same thing, but works.

Anyone any ideas why my method fails, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are running your query against enrity framework. the query is actually run at the sql server. since there is no support for your extension method there (as oppose to list) it fails.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if so, how come the ToList method works? That's also running against EF, and also can't be translated into a store method.

Comment: Anyone able to answer this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past (especially with LINQ-to-Entities) and the general solution is to use [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to build up the LINQ at compile time rather than deferring it to run-time.

Have you tried this:

```cs
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        observableCollection.Add(item);
    }

    return observableCollection;
}
```

I don't know if that would make any difference but it's worth a shot.

**As to [omer schleifer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143712/exception-trying-to-create-an-observablecollection-in-an-extension-method#15143926):**

An example of getting Entity Framework to allow extension methods is trying to generalize its `dbContext.Set<T>` moniker. Instead of doing this:

```cs
dbContext.People.Where(p => p.Id == 1234);
```

I wanted to be able to do this:

```cs
dbContext.Get<Person>(p => p.Id == 1234);
```

This method will not work:

```cs
public static T Get<T>(this DapperDbContext dbContext, int id, string property = "Id") where T : class
{
    return dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(t => (int)t.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(t) == id);
}
```

However, this one does work:

```cs
public static T Get<T>(this DapperDbContext dbContext, int id, string property = "Id") where T : class
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, property)
        , Expression.Constant(id)), parameter);
    return dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(lambda);
}
```

You might be able to do something similar for your scenario.

Hope this helps.